# Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a simple lists with items, but doesn't work and I dont know why. If I add "manually" these items, works. Sry for my english.

```
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          <li key={index}><span>{item.title}</span></li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const items = [
  {
      title: "asd0",
      image: ""
  },
  {
      title: "asd1",
      image: ""
  },
  {
      title: "asd2",
      image: ""
  }
]
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: are you using typescript or javascript?

Comment: Im using typescript

Comment: you need to define type of items array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use TypeScript, you need to use something called interfaces and be specific about types with your data.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

To be able to render items, the array needs to be moved to inside the component. Here is index.js:

```
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
  const items = [
    {
        title: "asd0",
        image: ""
    },
    {
        title: "asd1",
        image: ""
    },
    {
        title: "asd2",
        image: ""
    }
  ]
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          <li key={index}><span>{item.title}</span></li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```